# How to hide zero values in pie chart - MPChart android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there way to suppress zero value text from MP android chart (pie chart)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about that?

```
if(value > 0) dataSet.add(...)
else {
   // do nothing
}
```

Or write your own `ValueFormatter` to suppress zeros.

Comment: I have done the same . Is there any other option in MP chart

Answer (score 7):

Use custom formatter and return empty string if value==0.0f

```
public class CustomPercentFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public CustomPercentFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0");
    }

    public CustomPercentFormatter(DecimalFormat format) {
        this.mFormat = format;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        if (value == 0.0f)
            return "";
        return mFormat.format(value) + " %";
    }
}
```

set formatter :

```
lineData.setValueFormatter(new CustomPercentFormatter());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a new Formatter for `MPChart` as **Ali Zarei** declared in his answer. But you may still need the digits setup option of library which already implemented in `DefaultValueFormatter`

To achieve this, you can just create a new formatter and extend it from `DefaultValueFormatter` and `Override` the `getFormattedValue` method of `DefaultValueFormatter` and check if the value is bigger than 0 or not.

```
public class NonZeroChartValueFormatter extends DefaultValueFormatter {

    public NonZeroChartValueFormatter(int digits) {
        super(digits);
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex,
                                    ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        if (value > 0) {
            return mFormat.format(value);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've run into a similar problem. I want to hide the labels for 0 values in PieChart and I still want to keep them in the legend. I override the ValueFormatter but only manage to hide 0 values not the labels. Any advives? Please help.

Comment: this solution will hide 0 labels but 0 values still'll be kept as a piechart entry. if you don't want to keep it as an entry you need to check if value 0 and and don't add it as an entry.

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin Developers:**

```
class MyCustomValueFormatter : ValueFormatter() {
override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
    return if (value == 0f) {
        ""
    } else {
        value.roundToInt().toString() + " %"
    }
  }
}
```

and use this like

```
pieData.setValueFormatter(MyCustomValueFormatter())
```

Comment: I was also looking for this. Your's answer is the only one which worked :)